# Swift 4 - UIActivityViewController for Outlook

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to use UIActivityViewController for outlook only...I was able to get my UIActivityViewController working like so:

```
//Define HTML String

        var htmlString = ""

        //Add the headings to HTML String table

        htmlString += "<table border = '1' cellspacing='0' align = 'center'><tr><th>Job #</th><th>Task</th><th>Date</th></tr>"

        //For each item in punch list data array

        for i in 0..<punchListData.count {

            //If the item is selected

            if punchListData[i].cellSelected {

                //Add data to the HTML String

                htmlString += "<tr><td>" + jobList[i % jobList.count] + "</td><td align = 'center'>" + taskData[i / jobList.count] + "</td><td>" + (punchListData[i].stringData)! + "</td></tr>"
            }
        }

        //Close the HTML table in the HTML String

        htmlString += "</table><h5>Please contact me if you have any questions <br /> Thank you.</h5>"

        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems : [htmlString], applicationActivities: nil)

        activityViewController.setValue("Schedule for Community", forKey: "Subject")

        activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = self.shareButton

        self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But I have a few issues:

1. The subject line is not working, I did some research and apparently setValue will not work for Outlook and that the first line can be the subject line, but I have no idea how to do that.
2. Is there away to exclude all activities except for Outlook?
3. Previously I was just using MFMailComposeViewController to compose an email, is there away of doing this for Outlook? Without UIActivityViewController?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5):

You can build your own UI and present it as you like, then convert arguments to a deeplink URL and pass it to the outlook app:

```
// MARK: - Errors
enum MailComposeError: Error {
    case emptySubject
    case emptyBody
    case unexpectedError
}

// MARK: - Helper function
func outlookDeepLink(subject: String, body: String, recipients: [String]) throws -> URL {
    guard !subject.isEmpty else { throw MailComposeError.emptySubject }
    guard !body.isEmpty else { throw MailComposeError.emptyBody }
    
    let emailTo = recipients.joined(separator: ";")
    
    var components = URLComponents()
    components.scheme = "ms-outlook"
    components.host = "compose"
    components.queryItems = [
        URLQueryItem(name: "to", value: emailTo),
        URLQueryItem(name: "subject", value: subject),
        URLQueryItem(name: "body", value: body),
    ]
    
    guard let deepURL = components.url else { throw MailComposeError.unexpectedError }
    return deepURL
}
```

#### Usage

```
try! UIApplication.shared.open(
    outlookDeepLink(
        subject: "subject",
        body: "body",
        recipients: ["example@email.com", "example2@email.com"]
    )
)
```

#### At last, Note that:

1. Don't forget to tell iOS you are going to call `ms-outlook`. (Add it to `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` in `info.plist`, Otherwise, You will get an clear error message in console if you forget it)
2. Also don't forget to check if the app actually exists before trying to open the url. (`canOpenURL` is here to help)

Comment: Yea this works very well, however when I select Outlook in UIActivityViewController, it just has the compose message popup, is there away of doing it like that? Instead of having the whole outlook app open. I know MFMailComposeViewController does was I am expecting.

Comment: I think `MFMailComposeViewController` is for native iOS Mail.app isn't it? Also `UIActivityViewController' involves anyone who can interact with that activity by default. If you want to be so specific to outlook, you may want to be specific in the approaching method like calling its deeplink or using their framework (if they have any).

Comment: Yea I believe so.